# jQuery: Why in the world will this element not hide on hover?

Tags: jquery, hover, hide, element

This is getting really frustrating now!

I've created a script that appends some content from another page to the body when you hover a special link. I also set it up so that whenever i move the mouse away from the link, the new element (with the loaded content) hides. So far, so good. The problem is that sometimes when i move the cursor away from the link too fast, the script doesn't react (or something). Ah well, i thought, and just added this evil code that refuses to work:

```
$('#userBubble').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Now, is there anything wrong with that? I've tried using mouseenter instead, but no luck with that either. I've also tried putting it inside a $(document).ready() function - no luck there either. #userBubble is the the container of the content loaded on hover, and the name is correct. I can console.log #userBubble, so it does in fact exist.

Any ideas what's messing this up? I get no errors, it just doesn't work.

Comment: How many of these `id="userBubble"` elements are on the page?

Comment: More code please.  Not sure about your first paragraph there.  You have a link to the page thats messing up?

Comment: @Nick, one. I know you can't have several elements with he same id. @Blank, i'm running it locally. I might post the entire page if i can'figure fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that user ID is unique in the DOM and that the element exists when you bind(or use `live`).

Change it to a class and use live.  I bet it works.

```
<img id="userBubble" class="userBubble"/>

$('.userBubble').live("mouseover", function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. The ID was already unique, but it worked after changing it to live(). Thanks a bunch man!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because the element does not yet exist when you add the handler. Try

```
$('#userBubble').live('mouseover', function() {
   $(this).hide();
});
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$('#userBubble').mouseover(function(event) {

        $(event.target).hide();

});
```

EDIT: Ohw, didn't quite read your question well.
Like **Spiny Norman** said, you have to use 'live' or 'delegate' ; )

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have loaded the html-div before you set the event:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#test').mouseover(function () { $(this).hide(); })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">This will hide!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked with hover

```
$('#userBubble').hover(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2n2kJ/

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
    $("#hoverHide").mouseover( function ()
    {
        $(this).hide();
    } );
} );
```

If that does not work, try this:

```
$(document).ready( function()
{
    $("#hoverHide").mouseover( function ()
    {
        $("#hoverHide").hide();
    } );
} );
```

If neither of those works, the it seems likely that you have a syntax error somewhere on your page.  Perhaps in the `.ready` function declaration.